# Why doesn't the TensorFlow WHL file contain all required dependencies?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

system: windows 10 64 bit,python 3.6.5 64 bit. Use Anaconda. CUDA 10.0, cuddn installed.

good day. For security reasons, our company has denied access to the Internet. I downloaded from the official website TF tensorFlow whl package:

```
https: //storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I try to install it using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade D:\tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following message:

```
collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0)
Retrying ....after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError'
......
could not find a version that satifies the requirement keras-preprocessing=>1.0.5.....
no matching distribution found for keras-preprocessing=>1.0.5 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0)
```

When restarting, some other TensorFlow dependency will not be found, as I understand it, pip does not see any dependencies at all

I thought that the WHL package has all the necessary dependencies, but when installing pip it tries to download something from the Internet. Tell me what am I doing wrong?

pip check tensorflow result:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip check tensorflow

tensorflow 1.10.0 requires absl-py, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires astor, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires gast, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires grpcio, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires protobuf, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires tensorboard, which is not installed.
tensorflow 1.10.0 requires termcolor, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires absl-py, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires astor, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires gast, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires google-pasta, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires grpcio, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires keras-applications, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires keras-preprocessing, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires protobuf, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires tensorboard, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires tensorflow-estimator, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 requires termcolor, which is not installed.
distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 has requirement numpy<2.0,>=1.14.5, but you have numpy 1.14.3.
tensorflow-gpu 1.14.0 has requirement wrapt>=1.11.1, but you have wrapt 1.10.11.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I thought that the WHL package has all the necessary dependencies

No. Wheels don't contain all dependencies and they shouldn't, otherwise each wheel would be extremely bloated up. If you have to install `tensorflow-gpu` (or any other wheel) on a machine with no internet access, do the following steps:

1. On a machine *with* internet access, run:

   ```
   \> pip download tensorflow-gpu --dest some\dir
   ```

   (you can run this command with passing as `--dest` the directory that contains the downloaded `tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` so you don't have to download it again)

   This will download `tensorflow-gpu` and all its dependency tree.
2. Now transfer the directory (with all the files downloaded) to the machine *without* internet access and run:

   ```
   \> pip install tensorflow-gpu --no-index --find-links some\dir
   ```

   `--no-index` will instruct `pip` not to look up online for packages, `--find-links` will point to local directory where the packages can be found for installation.