# Offline python package installation needs to connect?

Tags: python, pip, package

Although I have downloaded a .whl package offline, I have not been able to install it offline since it needs to connect to pypi server. What can I do?

I have downloaded the package from PyPI and tried to install it. It is really weird that it wants to connect to the web again. How can I fix this?

```
pip install Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```

I expected that it installs it. But, the following message says that it needs to connect to the web.

The message:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000230B937FA20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/keras-preprocessing/
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from Keras==2.2.4) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 (from Keras==2.2.4)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57083464

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Packages Offline Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/python-packages-offline-installation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a relative or absolute path.

**Linux:**

```
pip install ./Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```

or

```
pip install /my/path/to/Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```

**Windows:**

```
pip install .\Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```

or

```
pip install C:\my\path\to\Keras-2.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user
```